# Memory leaks on realm database file

Tags: android, database, memory-leaks, realm

I found strange behaviour of database file when the `RealmObject` model contain byte array field. It's image in my case. I will try to explain this step by step.

First run of applications creates database file which have size **4MB** - it's not contain any objects of application.

- Insert object **A** with size of image - *1MB* => DB size = **5MB**
- Remove *image* from object **A** (`setImage(null)`), but object stil here => DB size = **5MB**
- Insert object **B** which contains image with size - *1MB* => DB size = **6MB**
- Remove object **A** => DB size = **6MB**
- Remove object **B** => DB size = **6MB**
- Insert object **C** which contains image with size - *2MB* => DB size = **6MB**

#### Conclusions

If you allocate database file up to ~1GB (insert only 64 image with size 16MB), your application forever will be works with it. Even if you remove all objects.

#### Questions

1. Why removing image from object **A** not release space from database file?
2. Why after removing image from object **A** and inserting of object **B** with same image, size of database file was increased on image size? From **5MB** to **6MB**.
3. Why object **C** not allocate additional space?
4. Which way I can release memory of `byte[]` field or shrink database file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you're not calling `Realm.compactRealm()`, ever

Comment: @EpicPandaForce when I need to call this method?

Comment: Typically I count the number of open activities, and I call compact when it reaches 0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, is it Ok, if I will run `Realm.compactRealm()` at application startup?

Comment: I tried that but it makes startup a bit slow in my opinion.

Comment: If you always close the Realm instance when you done with it (especially in the non-looper thread!), i don't really think you need to call `compactRealm` ever. Since as you noticed in your question 3, Realm will reuse the free spaces of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm Core uses a fairly complicated scheme when it determines how much file space it needs.

To shrink the db file, you must call `Realm.compactRealm()` manually.  Normally this is not necessary because, as you've noticed, the database engine re-uses space in the file.

Also, as you've noticed, compacting the file can take noticeable time.  If it is necessary to do it, it is best to do it infrequently and when your app is idle.